# copy to output directory file delete

Tags: wpf

i find that to play video files using mediaelement, we need to set the file's Copy To Ouput Directory to Copy Always. is there any option to auto delete the file from the output directory after it has been used? because if there's hundreds of video that has been played by the application, then it will take a massive amount of storage, right? because from what i seen, this copy to ouput directory will create the duplicate of the files, from it's original source path. please enlighten me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to copy the files to the output directory, you can set the source as follows:

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri (System.IO.Path.Combine(dirWithVids, fileName) 
                               ,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

Comment: i did exactly like what you said, but the video cannot be played. only after i set the file's Copy To Ouput Directory to Copy Always, then only it can be played.

Comment: @imin Is it a relative path or an absolute path? Are you sure the path is correct? (check with File.Exists)